# How can I join data from two tables and insert the result into a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select-insert

I have a table for my products and my key is `Pid`.

Each product can have several types of modes that are registered in the table `TB_Types`.

`did` is an identity column (key), `pid` is foreign key to products table:

| did | pid | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | type1 |
| 2 | 1 | type2 |
| 3 | 2 | type3 |
| 4 | 2 | type4 |

Now we have a table where each product can have a different number table name: `TB_Count`

Like the table below:

`cid` is an identity column (key), `pid` is a foreign key to the products table

| cid | pid | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 |
| 6 | 2 | 1000 |
| 7 | 2 | 5000 |
| 8 | 2 | 10000 |

Initially, the customer wanted each product to have different types and numbers, but now the count table must be changed as follows and the count that was for each product must be for each type.

I created a table as it should be.

New table name: `tb_newcount`

`id` is an identity column (key), `did` is a foreign key to the `TB_Types` table.

| id | did | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 |
| 4 | 2 | 25 |
| 5 | 2 | 50 |
| 6 | 2 | 100 |
| 7 | 3 | 5000 |
| 8 | 3 | 10000 |
| 9 | 3 | 15000 |
| 10 | 4 | 5000 |
| 11 | 4 | 10000 |
| 12 | 4 | 15000 |

If I can move the information to the new table as it was said, the problem will be solved.

I hope I have said what I mean.

Note: The number of products is close to 5,000 and the number of types is 2000 and the number of count is about 2000 records.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `INNER JOIN` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tb_newcount (did, count)
select did, count
  from TB_Types t join TB_Count c on c.pid = t.pid
```